# How to derive the Tf of an amplifier from its datasheet?

Tags: current, amplifier, datasheet, control-system, transfer-function

I am designing a control system, where the forward path has an amplifier in Howland's current pump configuration. I want to derive the TF of the current pump, and also take into consideration the Poles and zeroes inherited from the used amplifier. My approach was appointing Vo = A(V+ - V-) and after i derive Io/Vin i replace the Gain A in the equation with (A/(S + Wp)) but till now i am failing miserably, so any help would be appreciated.

[image: Howland's current pump]

Comment: [A possibly useful document](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&ved=0ahUKEwj7gLyRo9_ZAhXDKsAKHRfrAggQFgheMAU&url=http%3A%2F%2Fd1.ourdev.cn%2Fbbs_upload782111%2Ffiles_47%2Fourdev_694588RI0RBJ.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0qI6zL74oR6UPjyhwTHhGe)

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately this doesn't help as i want to take into consideration the poles and zeroes resulting from the Amplifier.

Comment: Use a sim for best effect.

Comment: could you elaborate on that ??!

Comment: Use a circuit simulation tool.